# Open sub-subfolder in Windows namespace extension

Tags: winapi, com, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I'm implementing a Basic Folder Object for a namespace extension composed by folders and subfolders (the junction point is a filesystem folder, which is empty). I've implemented `IShellFolder`, and support returning `IContextMenu` in `ShellFolderImpl::GetUIObjectOf`.

Suppose that I have the following folders (where A and A\B are "virtual" folders fabricated by `IShellFolder::EnumObjects`)

```
 C:\test.{74660590-4BEF-4BF4-9C85-5FAE0E084926}
 C:\test.{74660590-4BEF-4BF4-9C85-5FAE0E084926}\A
 C:\test.{74660590-4BEF-4BF4-9C85-5FAE0E084926}\A\B
```

I'm able to open `C:\test.{74660590-4BEF-4BF4-9C85-5FAE0E084926}`, and it lists the folder A.  When I double-click (or select Open from context menu) on folder A, that folder is opened and subfolder B is listed in the view.

Problem: that only works for folders directly under `C:\test.{74660590-4BEF-4BF4-9C85-5FAE0E084926}`. **The context menu is not displayed for subfolder B** (and `GetUIObjectOf` is never called, even though `IShellFolder:Initialize` is called with the right PIDL).

In the relevant part of `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand`, I open the subfolder by doing

```
 SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei = { 0 };
 sei.cbSize = sizeof(sei);
 sei.fMask = SEE_MASK_IDLIST | SEE_MASK_CLASSNAME;
 sei.lpIDList = pidl; // the fully qualified PIDL
 sei.lpClass = TEXT("folder");
 sei.hwnd = pcmi->hwnd;
 sei.nShow = pcmi->nShow;
 sei.lpVerb = cmd.verb.w_str();
 BOOL bRes = ::ShellExecuteEx(&sei);
 DeletePidl(pidl);
 return bRes?S_OK:HR(HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError()));
```

Comment: Try implement IDataObject interface.